# How to set ShiftHue filter from outside of Image declaration in KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

In, KineticJS, how can i set ShiftHue filter from outside of Image declaration?
I can set Brighten filter using following code:

```
image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Brighten);
image.setFilterBrightness(Math.round(slider.value));
```

What about ShiftHue filter?

Comment: Have you got the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use filter method on Kinetic's image object
and draw layer again

```
var stage = addStage();
var darth, layer;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  darth = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    image: imageObj,
    draggable: true
  });

  layer.add(darth);
  stage.add(layer);

  darth.cache();
  darth.filters([Kinetic.Filters.HSL]);
  darth.hue(0);
  layer.draw();
};
imageObj.src = 'assets/lion.png';

$('.update-hue').click(function(){
  darth.hue( parseInt($(this).attr('data-hue'), 10) );
  layer.draw();
});
```